# Why I can't change style in mxEvent.CHANGE event first time?

Tags: events, mxgraph

I just want to change some style when the CHANGE event fired.But when I change the model by insert or move a vertex or edge, the style didn't change. And the changed vertex will change it's style after I change anything again. Is anybody konws why?

Here is my code:

```
graph.getModel().addListener(mxEvent.CHANGE, function(sender, evt){
        if(graphInited){
            graph.getModel().beginUpdate();
            try {
                  var changes = evt.getProperty('edit').changes;
                  for (var i = 0; i < changes.length; i++) {
                      var change = changes[i];
                      var state = graph.view.getState(change.cell);
                      if(state!=null){//color #1C86EE means new insert
                          if(state.style[mxConstants.STYLE_IMAGE_BACKGROUND]!="#1C86EE" 
                          && state.style[mxConstants.STYLE_STROKECOLOR]!="#1C86EE" 
                          && state.style[mxConstants.STYLE_FONTCOLOR]!="#1C86EE"){
                              graph.setCellStyles(mxConstants.STYLE_IMAGE_BACKGROUND, '#68228B', [change.cell]);
                              graph.setCellStyles(mxConstants.STYLE_STROKECOLOR, '#68228B', [change.cell]);
                          }
                      }
                  }
            } finally {
                graph.getModel().endUpdate();
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

I made more recon and fond simpler solution than in my first answer.

You need to add:

1. `evt.consume()`
2. `graph.refresh()`

So final code would looks like:

```js
graph.getModel().addListener(mxEvent.CHANGE, function(sender, evt){
    if(graphInited){
        graph.getModel().beginUpdate();
        evt.consume();
        try {
                var changes = evt.getProperty('edit').changes;
                for (var i = 0; i < changes.length; i++) {
                    var change = changes[i];
                    var state = graph.view.getState(change.cell);
                    if(state!=null){//color #1C86EE means new insert
                        if(state.style[mxConstants.STYLE_IMAGE_BACKGROUND]!="#1C86EE" 
                        && state.style[mxConstants.STYLE_STROKECOLOR]!="#1C86EE" 
                        && state.style[mxConstants.STYLE_FONTCOLOR]!="#1C86EE"){
                            graph.setCellStyles(mxConstants.STYLE_IMAGE_BACKGROUND, '#68228B', [change.cell]);
                            graph.setCellStyles(mxConstants.STYLE_STROKECOLOR, '#68228B', [change.cell]);
                        }
                    }
                }
        } finally {
            graph.getModel().endUpdate();
            graph.refresh();
        }
    }
});
```